# mysql- Averaging values every n row with same id

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I try to do something in a Perl script, but I was wondering if there was an easier and faster way to do it directly through SQL.

First, here is an extract of the table I'm getting values from (the time column is a timestamp) :

```
|  Computer  |    TIME    |   CPU   |
| Computer-1 | 1418115601 |      67 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418115601 |      31 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418115601 |      39 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418115601 |      39 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418115601 |      37 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418115601 |      38 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418115601 |      54 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418115601 |       0 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418115601 |      52 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418116501 |      28 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418116501 |      30 | 
| Computer-3 | 1418116501 |      33 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418116501 |      23 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418116501 |       5 |
| Computer-2 | 1418116301 |       5 |
```

Now, I have like 500 or 600K rows in this table. I use it to create graphs. I simply retrieve the values from a Perl script then generate a graph but anyway. The thing is these measures are taken every 5 minutes. So if I create graph for a whole day I will have 288 "points" ((60/5)*24) per computer.

My question is, if I want a bigger granularity for my graph, let's say only 96 points (one measure every 15 minutes), how do I do that ?

In this case, I would have to find a way to tell "for every identical ID (computer in this case) take the last 3 values you found for it (I order by date so there should be no problem), average them, and give me the result".

The problem is I don't know how to do that, moreover, the TIME column might also be a problem. What will he do with that ? Is it possible to precise something like "After you averaged the last 3 values of CPU, just let TIME of the last row to fill the new averaged row" ? Or actually I could also just also average the time and that would still work...

Thank you all by advance :)

EDIT :

Some wanted an exemple of output I would like so here it is :
(In this exemple we imagine I only have 2 computers and 6 values for each)

With a normal request I would have this

```
mysql> SELECT Computer, TIME, CPU FROM myTable order by date;

|  Computer  |    TIME    |   CPU   |
| Computer-1 | 1418115601 |      10 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418115601 |      30 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418115701 |      15 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418115701 |      40 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418115801 |      15 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418115801 |      50 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418115901 |      12 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418115901 |      50 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418116101 |      10 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418116101 |      40 | 
| Computer-1 | 1418116201 |      11 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418116201 |      35 |
```

And I would like the average of the last 3 values with the same ID (Computer), so :

```
|  Computer  |    TIME    |   CPU   |
| Computer-1 | 1418115801 |   13.33 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418115801 |      40 |
| Computer-1 | 1418116201 |      11 | 
| Computer-2 | 1418116201 |   41.66 |
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the desired results that you are looking for?

Comment: Hm... I'm envisioning adding a user defined variable that increments by one for each different time interval.  And then using it and a mod operator so that if remainder is 1 return those rows...  This in effect would return the first group of time, the 4th, the 7th, 10th and so on... is that what you're after?

Comment: SELECT FLOOR(time/900)*900, AVG(thing) FROM my_table GROUP BY FLOOR(time/900)*900

Comment: Are those commas in `CPU` decimal points or value delimiters?

Comment: The commas are decimal, i'm European we use commas but i'll use a point you're right it will be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mimic the analytic function ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) which is not available in MySQL. You use variables for that in MySQL.

We number the rows per computer 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. Then we divide by 3 getting 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, etc. Thus we get a grouping criteria to aggregate on:

```
select computer, max(time), avg(cpu)
from
(
  select 
    @row_number := case when @computer = computer then @row_number + 1 else 0 end as row_number,
    @computer := computer as computer,
    time, 
    cpu
  from mytable
  cross join (select @row_number := -1, @computer := '') as t
  order by computer, time
) as t
group by computer, row_number div 3
order by computer, row_number div 3;
```

I found the row_number technique in Pinal Dave's blog here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/

Comment: WOW, i'm pretty sure that actually works !! I'm checkin in detail because I have a lot more values in reality, but so far so good :D I'll come back tommorow to check the answer if it works ! (Only missing thing was an "as t" right after the last ")". Otherwise you get an error.

Comment: I'm glad this works for you. Thanks for the hint that the derived table needs an alias. I work with Oracle most of the time, which doesn't need it (which I consider a convenient extension to the SQL standard). I'll update my answer.